# Error signing code and adding Policy Entry

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, policy, jks

I have a Java certificate I'm trying to implement in a server. The files I need are stored in the following path:

D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin

I believe the next step to get this to work is to add a Policy Entry with a SignedBy Alias using the Policy Tool. To do this, I need to specify the keystore that I'm using, in this case it's jarsignstore.jks. However, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCfSi.png) when I try adding it. I've already tried putting the slashes both ways and making sure that permissions to access these files are open to any user.

If I continue without specifying the keystore into Add Policy Entry, I add the alias of the signature (cecjarsigner) and the permission for users to read the files. However, when I click Done, I get [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVX8d.png).

I'm not sure how to continue or how to solve this.